# moment generating function , for iid

Tags: probability, density-function, moment-generating-functions

[image]

since this pdf is continuous between 0 and 1 i was wondering how i would find the moment generating function of the sum of X(i) .

Comment: Can you find the moment generating function for $X_1$? Do you know how to combine the moment generating functions for sums of independent random variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$M_{Y}(t)=E[e^{tY}]=E[e^{t\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}}]=E[\prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{t{X_i}}]$$

Using the independence of the $X_i$'s

$$E[\prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{t{X_i}}]=\prod_{i=1}^{n}E[e^{t{X_i}}]$$

Using the density function of $X_i$

$$E[e^{t{X_i}}]=\int_{0}^{1}{e^{t{x}}2xdx}=\frac{2(e^t(t-1)+1)}{t^2}$$

Finally,

$$M_{Y}(t)=\left(\frac{2(e^t(t-1)+1)}{t^2}\right)^n$$

Comment: why is the answer to the power of n at the end

Comment: if i were to find the mean from this moment generating function i woudnt be able to make t = 0 as that would not work or would i make t = 1 leaving the mean for this moment generating function equal  2^n

Comment: First question: What ist $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n c$, where $c=E[e^{t{X_i}}]$ ?

Comment: woudn't it be the answer canardini has given for My(t)

Comment: Second question: Calculate $\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{2(e^t(t-1)+1)}{t^2}$ and use l´hospital.

Comment: Have a look at the first and second line of the answer. Then $M_{Y}(t)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}E[e^{t{X_i}}]=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n c$

Comment: for the second question i differentiated the top and bottom parts twice to get rid of the t at the bottom leaving me with 1 as the answer for the second question , im not sure if i am correct , i think i am wrong

Comment: Nice that you managed the first question. Can ´t you comprehend the line I´ve posted at last?

Comment: so 1 is not the correct answer for question 2 ?

Comment: @nathan I wanted to say it the other way round, sorry. Yes, the answer to the second question is indeed 1. Nice job.

Comment: so im assuming the answer for the mean would be 1^n = 1

Comment: That´s true, nathan.

Comment: @nathan If you don´t have any further questions please mark the answer as accepted.